# Finding variables in ruby on rails applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, associations

I have two tables: one called styles, which has 5 attributes (plus id and created_at) and another called recommender, which has 6 attributes (plus id and created_at).

Once I have defined the 5 attributes on the Styles table, I want to be able to show an entry from the recommender table that has 5 attributes matching the attributes in the styles table.

I have tried a few combinations of Model.find and Model.where to get it, but nothing seems to work.

Here is the  styles_controller.rb

```
def show
@style = Style.find(params[:id])
bt = @style.bodytype
n = @style.need
t = @style.texture
c = @style.color
st = @style.statement   
@recommender =  Recommender.with_bodytype(params[:bt]).with_need(params[:n]).with_texture(params[:t]).with_color(params[:c]).with_statement(params[:st])
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @style }
 end
end
```

The message I get is:
Undefined method `with_bodytype' for #

So, thanks to @bravenewweb for helping out... But there are still some issues:

I think I figured out the problem, but I am not sure how to fix it.

The production environment has Recommender with all its data (I put it there) and so does development.

Recommender exists now at Heroku, but not with any data. And I am not sure how to put it there.

I think the problem is that the Production db is SQLite, even though it is only supposed to work in development and test. So how do I get the production db to talk to Heroku?

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be much easier than that, ActiveRecord's find method will by default return the first record that matches. What you want to do is chain the attribute names with and, then pass the query attributes in using the same order as the method name

```
@recommender = Recommender.find_by_bodytype_and_need_and_texture_and_color_and_statement(bt, n, t, c, st)
```

If you want to find all the records matching those params, you just need to start it with

```
@recommender = Recommender.find_all_by_bodytype_and_need_and_texture_and_color_and_statement(bt, n, t, c, st)
```

Comment: this solution will work, and it has a sort of simple elegance that the `.where` approach does not.  I didn't recommend it because I had read that [dynamic finders were being removed from Rails 4.0](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html#active-record-deprecations) in favor of the AREL-like syntax.  While the deprecation does apply to your second example, the first `.find_by_...` appears to live on.  Too bad IMHO -- the magic of these finders was a thing that made be fall in love with Rails.  On the other hand, .where and others is more flexible, I guess.

Comment: Hey, I was ready to lay this one to rest, but alas, it will not work with HEROKU. It works fine locally. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Well, that doesen't make any sort of sense, heroku should have nothing to do with it, unless you are running a different version of rails locally than what you are running on heroku. I would suggest you troubleshoot why it's not working on heroku. Has your database been migrated, do the tables look the same, is there bad data in the table, etc..

Comment: If you log on to server and do rails c production, type Recommender (enter) -- This should show you the database fields that have been migrated, most likely its a missing field issue, or no records that match all 5 params

Comment: GRRRR! It seems like Recommender only exists in Development not in Production. I know this is pretty basic, but how can I get it to be available everywhere. I have done a bunch of db:migrate all day long.

Comment: Log onto your server, enter the apps main directory, and type "rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production", minus the quotes, and let me know if that works. Otherwise, the migrations have already ran, and if you are still setting the app up, I would recommend recreating the database via "rake db:drop RAILS_ENV=production && rake db:create RAILS_ENV=production && rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production" to rerun the migrations. Note that the latter will destroy any existing data in the database tables.

Comment: The first option worked. I can see Recommender in Production and Heroku consoles, but none of the data that is stored.

Comment: Probably because there is no data stored there yet as you just created the table on your production database :)

Comment: Fair enough :) Is there a way to transfer the data I Have in development?

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the `.with_<attribute>` methods (do they exist?), but it sounds like you want a straightforward where clause.  If I understand correctly you want to find all Recommenders who share the attributes of the selected style.  So something like

```
@recommender = Recommender.where("bodytype = :bodytype AND need = :need AND texture = :texture AND color = :color AND statement = :statement", [:bodytype => @style.bodytype, :need => @style.need, :texture = @style.texture, :color => @style.color, :statement => @style.statement]).first
```

You could also use `?` for each of the named placeholders, but when you have lots of conditions, this reads a little more clearly.

Also, this probably isn't a `show` method, it's more like `index` since the query could return more than one result, right?  If so, maybe your instance variable should be plural (`@recommenders`).  Or maybe I am missing something?

Comment: Yes, that is what I was looking for, a very straightforward clause. However, it didn't work. :( I get the following message now, coming from the show.html. It is not supposed to return more than one result.undefined method `bodytype' for []:ActiveRecord::Relation
Extracted source (around line #10):

7: <p>
8:   <b>Bodytype:</b>
9:   <%= @style.bodytype %>
10:   <%= @recommender.bodytype %>
11:   
12: </p>
13:

Comment: Ah yes ... I have updated the answer.  `ActiveRecord::Relation` is a class that's very close to old-style Rails finders, but much more clever.  It gets some of its cleverness by not executing queries until needed.  If you pass a method like `.first` or `.all` to the class it will force it to run the SQL query.  All I did was add `.first` to the end of the query (since you expect it to return just one record), and now it should return an instance of `Recommender`, instead of just `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

Comment: It seems the answer is getting closer. But I am still getting an error message. undefined method `bodytype' for nil:NilClass - coming from show.html again.

Comment: This is a different error; now instead of returning an `ActiveRecord::Relation` it's running the SQL and (likely) returning no results, in which case the value in `@recommender` is `nil`.  Your controller should test for this case and handle it.  Have you looked in `logs/development.log`?  It will show you the SQL that Rails ran for you -- perhaps there are no records that match all 5 criteria.  If you want to experiment, run `rails console` and paste in the query.  Then you can try variants and see what's not working.  The secret to learning Rails is to know how to track down problems.

Comment: I saw your comment to bravenewweb. I tried your option in the console and I was getting strange syntax errors still. Thank you so much for all your help and patience with a newbie. :-)

Comment: Sure!  So my final exhortation...  On Stack Overflow, when someone answers your question and provides useful information that others might benefit from, you're encouraged to "upvote" it -- this will help the best answers sort to the top.  So give @bravenewweb props for the answer that worked for you!  And anyone else :P

Answer (score 1):

You can have has_one association having composite key as [bodytype, need, texture, color, statement] if you want style to be uniquely associated to recommender.